# Connect to Windows 2003 64 bits IIS FTP 6 in Passive Mode not working

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, ftp, passive

I have a Windows 2003 64bit Data Center Edition, with IIS/FTP 6 installed. The FTP Site is the default site that was created when I installed IIS/FTP. I have setup FTP so that it won't allow Anonymous connections. The home folder is `C:\Inetpub\ftproot`, with Read and Write permission. The ACL for the ftproot follows:

```
Administrators: Full Control
CREATOR OWNER: Full Control
SYSTEM: Full Control
Users: Read
```

I have created a Virtual Directory called `VirtualDir`, that points to `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\VirtualDir`, with Read and Write permission, and the ACL for the folder VirtualDir follows:

```
Administrators: Full Control
virtualdir: Modify (Read/Write)
IIS_WPG: Read
InternetGuest: Deny Write
SYSTEM: Full Control
Users: Read
```

I created a local User with the name `virtualdir` that belongs to the Users group and, as you can see above, has Read/Write permissions on the `VirtualDir` folder inside `wwwroot`.
I can only list the contents of the Virtual Directory `VirtualDir` using Active connection mode. With Passive Mode, it's impossible. I've tried turning off the server's firewall, and I've added Exceptions for port 21 AND for the `C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\inetinfo.exe` file, with no effect. I'm sure it's not a client firewall issue, because I can connect with any other FTP site, in active or passive mode, without a problem. Below is the log for FileZilla client when using Passive Mode:

```
Status: Connecting to 187.xxx.xxx.204:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER virtualdir
Response:   331 Password required for virtualdir.
Command:    PASS ************
Response:   230 User virtualdir logged in.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/virtualdir" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (187,xxx,xxx,204,19,139).
Command:    LIST
Response:   425 Can't open data connection.
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

When using Active mode, all goes well. Have I forgotten anything? Have I done something wrong? I don't think it's permission, since in Active Mode, everything goes fine.
Tks

Comment: is the server behind another level of firewall? That could be be blocking the passive FTP ports.

Comment: @MattB maybe... I'll check with the ISP. I concentrated on me doing something wrong with the configuration, that I forgot about the ISP

Comment: @MattB, you were rigth! Post it as an answer, so I can give up the credit! http://ajuda.uolhost.com.br/index.php?ind=106&p=resposta&res=1075

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passive FTP ports are being blocked by a firewall on the server side. There is a metabase property called PassivePortRange that allows you to specify the range of ports used for passive FTP, to match what is allowed through your firewall.

See these references:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0d2a9b2e-b697-4bb3-8a61-0fad73a1fa08.mspx?mfr=true

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d2405f36-06c3-4468-a8b0-eb0442ed1889.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Beware of this bug also... wasted an hour to figure it out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009506/passiveportrange-problem-in-iis6-ftp